# Reading the output of running a Process is null

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm trying to run a process that compiles an application (an old basic compiler). I purposely have an error in the application I'm trying to compile to see how I can read any output messages that might come back but I only see null in e.Data. Can someone tell me if there is something wrong in my code below for trying to read output or error data?

```
private static void RunProcess(string filename, string args)
{
    try
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        processStartInfo.FileName = filename;

        processStartInfo.Arguments = args;

        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var result = string.Empty;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
        {
            process.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;

            process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            Console.Write("Completed process with an exit code of: " + process.ExitCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

private static void Process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: Just tried to execute `RunProcess("cmd", null)` and I can see the process output. Are you sure the process you're launching (the old compiler) writes to the standard output? Can you launch the compiler from command line redirecting its output to the file, like `old_compiler parameters > build_log.txt` and check if it works?

Comment: I did that and build_log.txt was empty. I guess I can assume that it does not write to standard output??